# Standard answers to "why can't ____ be explained by ____ instead?"

Tags: discussion, questions, community-wiki

There are many questions which come up again and again, virtually every day, trying to propose an alternative explanation for a well-established principle.  I think it would be very useful to keep a list of best-explanations for why the established principle is the established principle, for quick reference (and when marking things as duplicates).  **Here are some of the common issues and best responses (*in my opinion*)**.  I hope that this question will open discussions about what other common duplicate questions are, and what the best answers are.

- **Galaxies are moving away from each other because of the expansion of space** (and not just because they don't like each other).

  - [Is it possible that galaxies' redshift is caused by something else than the expansion of space?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114990/is-it-possible-that-galaxies-redshift-is-caused-by-something-else-than-the-expa)
  - [Why the red-shift of distant galaxies is considered to be the effect of expanding spacetime?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38779/why-the-red-shift-of-distant-galaxies-is-considered-to-be-the-effect-of-expandin)
  - [How does measuring redshift make us conclude that rate universe expansion is accelerating?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108609/how-does-measuring-redshift-make-us-conclude-that-rate-universe-expansion-is-acc)
- **Galaxy rotation curves and 'missing mass' are Dark Matter** (and not because MOND / dyson spheres / really really really dark normal matter).

  - [Why isn't dark matter just ordinary matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/why-isnt-dark-matter-just-matter)
  - [How do we know Dark Matter is non baryonic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26778/how-do-we-know-dark-matter-is-non-baryonic/26779#26779)
  - [Does MOND make good predictions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5762/does-mond-make-good-predictions)
  - [Are modified theories of gravity credible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6561/are-modified-theories-of-gravity-credible)
  - [Do alternate theories for Dark Matter (like MOND) explain its effect on gravitational lensing?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123661/do-alternate-theories-for-dark-matter-like-mond-explain-its-effect-on-gravitat)
- **The speed of light is *really* a constant, from all reference frames** (even if you attach rockets to your rockets, in opposite direction of other rockets attached to the aether)

  - [Why and how is the speed of light in vacuum constant, i.e., independent of reference frame?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/why-and-how-is-the-speed-of-light-in-vacuum-constant-i-e-independent-of-refer)
  - [Wikipedia: Tests of Special Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_special_relativity#Constancy_of_the_speed_of_light)
- **You cannot measure both position and momentum exactly** (no matter how good you are at tennis).

  - [Isn't the uncertainty principles just a technological limitation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24068/isnt-the-uncertainty-principle-just-non-fundamental-limitations-in-our-current)
- **The double slit experiment cannot be explained by classical physics** (despite whatever interesting thing happening on your fishing trip last weekend).

Comment: @ACuriousMind I had been thinking about this stuff again lately, and perhaps I'll try to set something in motion in the coming months.

Comment: @Danu how about continuing what's set in motion here?  :)

Comment: There's no question here, and nothing to answer - even considering the relaxed standards by which we handle questions on meta, I don't think this works as written. But rather than close it as unclear or opinion-based, I'll mark it as a duplicate so it can serve as a signpost to the original proposal.